# Interop.excel Application to Azure Web app service

Tags: c#, excel, azure

After deploying my app service using Interop.Excel there is an exception as I need to have office in my azure portal.
I can't change my code to use any other library now, as I have done lot of code for my application.

Once looking for the solution I found some of these option

1. Using Excel add.Ins
2. Use Docker container
3. Deploy App in office enabled VM.
   Not sure how feasible is this option?.

Comment: Looking for similar kind of solution. It seems excel add-ins won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Azure Web App is a `PaaS` service, so we cannot add too many modifications to this service. So your first plan is not feasible.
2. It is possible and feasible to use `Container Docker`.
3. It is also feasible to purchase a VM virtual machine and install Office on the virtual machine to deploy a website.

**My Suggestion:**

1. The first choice is to use Container Docker to deploy your application.
2. You can also consider to use [**`Azure Cloud Services`**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/services/cloud-services/).
3. Finally, consider deploying the program by purchasing a azure VM.

**The Reason:**

1. Deploy the program through the container, still use azure web app services. The purpose of webapp is to allow developers to focus more on code development instead of server management. For the logs in the webapp, analysis and other content are very detailed, which can better monitor the operation of the web program. In addition, as far as I know, webapp fees should be relatively low.
2. Azure Cloud Services essentially also has a `VM`. Whether to use this service or not, you can choose according to your needs.
3. The charge of Azure VM should be higher than that of azure web app. The advantage of vm is that you can install any software you want to install or `third-party plug-ins`, which cannot be done by azure web app. Disadvantages, you need to be familiar with the use of `IIS`, and have an understanding of the server. In addition, sometimes when the official push for windows is upgraded, there may be downtime upgrades. This is the same as azure cloud services, which may require multiple instances to manage. Make sure that the program is always in the active state.

Comment: @Json Do you suggest me some documentation to use container with office installed. I could not find anything useful.

Comment: I would be glad to have some other option available as well something useful document for with Azure service with office

Comment: @meenu Try to search ‘Microsoft web office’ by google, you can open office doc,excel,pdf online on browser without any addin.